# How to reference an *.rst file from the docstring of a module using sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I wrote a little tutorial in `rst` format. Now for the documentation generated by `apidoc`, I would like to reference that tutorial in the docstring using:

```
:any:`<my_tut>`
```

Where `my_tut.rst` is in the top level directory of my Sphinx-documentation source-folder. However, I get the error

```
WARNING: 'any' reference target not found: my_tut
```

**Added info:**

The output of `apidoc` is not in the toplevel source folder, but in a subfolder called `code`.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the angle brackets? ``:any:`my_tut` ``. This would require a label defined as `.. _my_tut:`.

Comment: Works. Wonder why referencing the file does not.

Comment: To reference the file, use the `doc` role: ``:doc:`my_tut` ``.

Comment: I tried that, but it wouldn't work. If a file is in the source folder, I do not have to give a relative path, do I?

Comment: Perhaps you have to provide a relative path. Is the output from the docstring in a different folder than the output from my_tut.rst?

Comment: Yed. It is in a subfolder.

Comment: So does ``:doc:`../my_tut` `` work?

Comment: It does. Would you mind writing an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`:doc:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-doc) role can be used to create a cross-reference to my_tut.rst:

```
:doc:`my_tut`
```

If the link source and the link target are in different folders, that needs to be taken into account. With a target one level above the source, it would look like this:

```
:doc:`../my_tut`
```

---

An alternative is to add a [label](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref) immediately before the relevant heading in my_tut.rst and use that as the cross-reference target. If the label definition is `.. _my_label:`, you would reference it like this:

```
:any:`my_label`
```

You could also use `` :ref:`my_label` ``.